# Exception when using cassandra-unit to test cassandra

Tags: unit-testing, cassandra

In my Java-Mavan-Spring project I'm using [cassandra unit](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit) to try and test my DAO.

I created 2 files in my classpath:

1. A simple XML that describes my initial data
2. A cassandra configuration file (cassandra.yaml)

Here is my test class:

```java
public class UserProfilingCassandraDaoUTest extends BaseJunitTestCase {

    @Rule
    public CassandraUnit cassandraUnit = new CassandraUnit(new ClassPathXmlDataSet("cassandraTestValues.xml"), "cassandra.yaml", "127.0.0.1");

    private HectorCassandraConnection connection;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
    connection = Mockito.mock(HectorCassandraConnection.class);
    Mockito.when(connection.getKeyspace()).thenReturn(cassandraUnit.keyspace);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldHaveLoadTestDataSet() throws Exception {
    Assert.assertNotNull(cassandraUnit.keyspace);
    Assert.assertEquals(cassandraUnit.keyspace.getKeyspaceName(), "rtb");
    }

    @Test
    public void getUserStatsTest() {
      // Some Test
    }
}
```

This is my cassandraTestValues.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<keyspace xmlns="http://xml.dataset.cassandraunit.org">
    <name>rtb</name>
    <columnFamilies>
        <columnFamily>
            <name>my_column_family</name>
            <keyType>UTF8Type</keyType>
            <comparatorType>UTF8Type</comparatorType>
            <defaultColumnValueType>UTF8Type</defaultColumnValueType>
            <row>
                <key>12345__678_910</key>
                <column>
                    <name>Col1</name>
                    <value>6</value>
                </column>
                <column>
                    <name>Col2</name>
                    <value>6</value>
                </column>
                <column>
                    <name>Col3</name>
                    <value>3</value>
                </column>
            </row>
        </columnFamily>
    </columnFamilies>
</keyspace>
```

As I run my test I'm getting [this log](https://copy.com/evRatLdWNJvvXQrK) with [this error](https://copy.com/46s0WX6sVECBAtbD).

I have tried for hours many different methods to overcome the issue with no success.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit sad, but changing cassandra-unit version from 1.2.0.1 to 1.0.3.1 and it worked like a charm.
I got to the solution by importing [this project](https://github.com/pwyrwa/CassandraUnit) to my workspace. The imported project worked just fine and after compering both found that the difference between the versions is what causing the issue.

In addition, non of the later maven versions worked, meaning that all the version that came out after 1.0.3.1 failed (1.2.0.1, 1.1.2.1, 1.1.1.3, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.1, 1.1.0.1).

I hope this could save some time to someone in the future.. it sure took me a while.